# exception CertificateException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Tags: java, exception, ssl

Im trying read a URL using java

```
try{
    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(args[0]).openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0");
    c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.5");
    System.out.println(c.getResponseCode());
}catch(java.security.cert.CertificateException e){
    System.out.println("not valid");
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

when I use just the last catch on domains with invalid ssl certification, it throws `java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching <domainName> found`

but when I try to catch the exact exception for more works it doesn't compile and prints this error:

```
error: exception CertificateException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
    }catch(java.security.cert.CertificateException e){
    ^
```

how can I assure compiler that this catch is in the right place, or whats my problem?

Answer (score 0):

> when I use just the last catch on domains with invalid ssl certification, it throws java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching  found

No it doesn't. It throws an `SSLHandshakeException` wrapping that exception. Have another look.

> how can I assure compiler that this catch is in the right place

You can't. It isn't. The compiler is correct.

> what's my problem?

Exactly what the compiler says it is. You're catching an exception that isn't thrown. Remove the catch. Catch `SSLHandshakeException` if you like.